# How can I access media files in CSS? Django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I'd like to do something like this:

```
div#city{
    background-image: url("{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{city.city_image}}");
}
```

If I add the above as inline CSS within HTML it does produce the below path and it renders okay but I can't access it from CSS.

```
<div class="container" style="background-image:url('media/city_pictures/paris-france.jpg');">
        <div class="city_header">
            <h1> PARIS </h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

I can access Static images from CSS but not media images.

Comment: What do you mean you can't access it from css?

Comment: it doesn't render.

Comment: you said it does render, do you mean you can't access it from css file?

Comment: @almostabeginner exactly

Comment: Best way you can do that is if you do it in your base template. I don't think you can call template tags inside css files. I have experienced with the same issue in Javascript, you can't call the tags in js files, so instead, I just save it in a variable in base template, then i can use it in js. I'm sure same applies to css files.

Answer (score -1):

User relative paths, for example:

```
background: url('../media/city_pictures.jpg');
```

the above example is if media folder and your css folder is in the same folder.